# How can I check if an Element in my Lists points to my current element?

Tags: java, list, element

I'm working on a programming exercise, and I stumbled across a problem about "comparing" List objects for a method.

Goal: Check if the previous object in the List is null or if its next attributes points at my current object.

My idea was the following:

```
public ListElement (String info, ListElement next, ListElement prev) {
    this.info = info;
    this.next = next;
    this.prev = prev;
}

public boolean isDeleted() {
    ListElement prevElement = getPrev();
    ListElement nextElement = getNext();

    if(prevElement.next.info.equals(this.info))
        return false;
}
```

However, I'm not sure if I get the correct result / about the approach.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please write some test cases for your approach, and ask any question which comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "points to" means "is the exact same instance", you'd have to use `==` for comparison.

```
public boolean isDeleted() {
    return 
        // if the previous Object in the List is null 
        prev == null ||
        // if its next attributes points at my current Object
        next == this;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the reply. The Method is used to check if the Element is deleted from the list or not, the conditions to check for are if this previous Element equals null or if the previous Elements points at our Element, if it does not point a our Element the Element is deleted.

Comment: @Yohnson thanks for the clarification. In this case, your implementation would lead to a NPE. I updated the answer acordingly.

Comment: Why would it lead to a NPE though? As long as the Element is not deleted the prevElement.next.info should give me the info of the next or my current Element or not?

Comment: @Yohnson I was assuming you delete an element by setting its previous' next to `null`. Thinking about it again, that is propably not the case. I removed this part of the answer.